# If $\alpha(\theta+c)=R(\theta)\alpha(\theta)$ and $|\dot \alpha|=1$, must $R$ be constant?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, symmetry

Let $\alpha:\mathbb{S}^1\to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a $C^2$ curve satisfying $|\dot \alpha|=1$, and suppose that there exists a constant $c \in \mathbb{S}^1$ such that
$
\alpha(\theta+c)=R(\theta)\alpha(\theta)
$
holds for every $\theta$, where $R:\mathbb{S}^1 \to \text{SO}(2)$ is $C^1$.

Must $R$ be a constant map?

Differentiating, we get

$ \alpha'(\theta+c)=R'(\theta)\alpha(\theta)+R(\theta)\alpha'(\theta),
$
thus
$$
1=| \alpha'(\theta+c)|^2=|R'\alpha|^2+1+2\langle R'\alpha,R\alpha'\rangle.
$$
So
$$
|R'\alpha|^2+2\langle R'\alpha,R\alpha'\rangle=0.
$$

---

I am not sure how to continue.

Comment: Don't we have $|R'\alpha|^2\ge0$ and $\langle R'\alpha,R\alpha'\rangle\ge0$?

Comment: I don't see any obvious reason for the second expression to be nonnegative. Do you see such a reason?